# Use sub-/superscript and special characters in legend texts of R plots

Tags: r, plot, special-characters, legend, plotmath

I generate a plot for multiple datasets. Each of the datasets should get it's own legend, which might contain greek letters, plotmath symbols or sub and superscrition. I'd like to generate the legend-texts in a loop.

Bquote works fine, if there is only one legend text. If I try to add additinal legend texts, the plotmath-commads get lost,...

```
x <- 0:10
y1 = x * x
y2 = x * 10

plot (1,1, type="n", xlab=bquote(Omega), ylab="Y", las=1, xlim=range(x), ylim=range(y1, y2))
lines(x, y1, col=1, pch=1, type="b")
lines(x, y2, col=2, pch=2, type="b")

# generate legend texts (in a loop)
legend_texts = c(
  bquote(Omega^2)
  , bquote(Omega%*%10)
)
# Using a single bquote works fine:
#legend_texts = bquote(Omega^2)
#legend_texts = bquote(Omega%*%10)

legend(
  "topleft"
  , legend = legend_texts
  , col = c(1:2)
  , pch = c(1:2)
  , lty = 1
  )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change "legend_texts" to:

```
# generate legend texts (in a loop)
legend_texts = c(
  as.expression(bquote(Omega^2))
  , as.expression(bquote(Omega%*%10))
)
```

From the help page for `?legend`, the "legend" argument is described as:

> a character or expression vector. of length ≥ 1 to appear in the legend. Other objects will be coerced by as.graphicsAnnot.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Minor dyslexia here. The help page reads "expression vector", not "vector of expressions". :)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
 legend_texts = expression(
   Omega^2, Omega*10)

 legend(
   "topleft"
   , legend = legend_texts
   , col = c(1:2)
   , pch = c(1:2)
   , lty = 1
   )
```

I could not tell if you wanted `Omega^10` or `Omega*10` or `Omega%*%10` , but they all would produce acceptable plotmath expressions.

[image]

Comment: Better than my use of `as.expression` over and over. +1

Comment: When using the `expression` function, you create a multiple value expression vector by separating the elements with commas.

Comment: thanks. I just re-read the help page and came to that conclusion. :)